# No bluetooth on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: bluetooth, 17.10

I have an acer v5-471 running Xubuntu 17.10 and like i said in the title there is no bluetooth, the bluetooth icon doesn't show up, and bluetooth manager says "no bluetooth adapter found", **how can i fix this?**

here is the output for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

```
02:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:0724]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:6621]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b335 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.136099] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.441871] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x461f03)
[  105.885139] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  105.887120] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  105.887127] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  105.887130] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  105.887143] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 2110.196838] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x461f03)
[ 4668.244176] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 4668.244179] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 4668.244183] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Edit the question to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` thanks

Comment: i have added the output from the command you specified @Jeremy31

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have a bluetooth device installed

Comment: @Jeremy31 Had Xubuntu 16.10 before upgrading and everything used to work fine except for bluetooth audio

Comment: Going to follow this thread. I'm using 17.10 on my XPS 9560 and BT will randomly stop working. I can usually reboot 2-3 times and it'll suddenly work again. No idea why and can't find anything helpful out there.

Comment: AR9462 has a long history of spotty performance under Linux. Manufacturer's fault for not releasing drivers, not Ubuntu's fault. Please file a bug report against the  'linux' package using the `ubuntu-bug` application.